# Java Use of Getter for attribute of Type Rectangle2D returns Null value

Tags: java, methods, nodes, contains, shapes

When clicking on a panel onto which a graph is displayed I want to check whether the click qualifies as the clicking of a particular node of the graph. To do so I added a Rectangle2D shape as an attribute to the graph's node and then I use the "contains(Point point)" method to check whether the mouse click took place within the shape.

My problem now is that the compiler gives me a null pointer exception stating that the getter Method of the node for the shape attitude returns a value of null and that he therefore can not call the "contains(Point point)" method. I am clueless as to why this is the case because I have instantiated the attribute of Rectangle2D type beforehand.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you provide the code causing the problem ? Otherwise it's hard to know where to look to help you.

Comment: The attribute is probably never initialized or set.